# What does "@" mean in makefile?

Tags: makefile

We offen use `@echo "do..."` to letting to print only `do...`.
But who can tell me what is the mean of this condition ?

```
COUNT=$(shell ls | wc -l )
```

Then

```
@COUNT=$( shell ls | grep abc | wc -l )
```

What's the mean of the second?

Comment: Those two line ware used in one makefile.

Comment: We can't answer the question about `COUNT` because you don't give any context about where it appears.  The `@` token only has special meaning to make if it's at the beginning of a logical recipe line (that is preceded by a hard TAB character in a rule context).  If this line appears outside of a recipe then `@` has no special meaning to make, and the above statement merely sets the make variable named `@COUNT` to the output of the shell command `ls | grep abc | wc -l`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does prefix @- mean in makefile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305609/what-does-prefix-mean-in-makefile)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It disables printing the command line being executed. Any output from the command itself still appears. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861911/ignoring-at-symbol-in-makefiles) previous question or see this [Makefile](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/tools/make_example.html) reference.

Comment: Is it means that the second COUNT will just get a new value ?

Comment: The assignment operation doesn't change, it just happens silently.

Answer (score 4):

It will hide the output of the commandline when executing. Normally each command, when executing a rule, is printed to the console. This will suppress this output.

Comment: So how about the value of 'COUNT' at the second line ?

Comment: The value is unchanged, only the line is not echoed to the console. It's just a simple way to tidy up your ooutput for complex makefiles, so you can see what is relevant and hide the other stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I seen a makefile like this, first a line like VERSION=$(shell ... ) and then @VERSION=(shell ...). So I can not understand what this mean for it won't get a new value.