# What does prefix @- mean in makefile?

Tags: makefile

What does the prefix `@-` mean in a makefile? Any difference from using `@` without `-`? For example, in the following case:

```
ifndef NO_CBLAS
    @echo Generating cblas.h in $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR)
    @sed 's/common/openblas_config/g' cblas.h > $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR)/cblas.h
endif

ifndef NO_LAPACKE
    @echo Copying LAPACKE header files to $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY_DIR)
    @-install -pDm644 $(NETLIB_LAPACK_DIR)/lapacke/include/lapacke.h $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR)/lapacke.h
    @-install -pDm644 $(NETLIB_LAPACK_DIR)/lapacke/include/lapacke_config.h $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR)/lapacke_config.h
    @-install -pDm644 $(NETLIB_LAPACK_DIR)/lapacke/include/lapacke_mangling_with_flags.h $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR)/lapacke_mangling.h
    @-install -pDm644 $(NETLIB_LAPACK_DIR)/lapacke/include/lapacke_utils.h $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR)/lapacke_utils.h
endif
ifndef NO_STATIC
    @echo Copying the static library to $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY_DIR)
    @install -pm644 $(LIBNAME) $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY_DIR)
    @cd $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY_DIR) ; \
    ln -fs $(LIBNAME) $(LIBPREFIX).$(LIBSUFFIX)
endif
```

Comment: Section 5 [Writing Recipes in Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipes) of the `GNU make Manual` has information about both of these things in it. Specifically section 5.2 and 5.5.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Section 5 [Writing Recipes in Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipes) of the GNU make Manual has information about both of these things in it. Specifically section 5.2 and 5.5.

> 5.2 Recipe Echoing
>
> Normally make prints each line of the recipe before it is executed. We call this echoing because it gives the appearance that you are typing the lines yourself.
>
> When a line starts with ‘@’, the echoing of that line is suppressed. The ‘@’ is discarded before the line is passed to the shell. Typically you would use this for a command whose only effect is to print something, such as an echo command to indicate progress through the makefile:

and

> 5.5 Errors in Recipes
>
> After each shell invocation returns, make looks at its exit status. If the shell completed successfully (the exit status is zero), the next line in the recipe is executed in a new shell; after the last line is finished, the rule is finished.
>
> If there is an error (the exit status is nonzero), make gives up on the current rule, and perhaps on all rules.
>
> Sometimes the failure of a certain recipe line does not indicate a problem. For example, you may use the mkdir command to ensure that a directory exists. If the directory already exists, mkdir will report an error, but you probably want make to continue regardless.
>
> To ignore errors in a recipe line, write a ‘-’ at the beginning of the line’s text (after the initial tab). The ‘-’ is discarded before the line is passed to the shell for execution.