# Is it possible to enforce recipe echoing with GNU Make?

Tags: makefile

According to [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html), echoing of shell commands can be suppressed by prefixing the according lines with `@`.

Using the option `-n` or `--just-print`, one can make a dry run and print all those prefixed lines without actually doing them.

Is it possible  to execute the make recipes **and** print the shell commands at the same time? Put differently, can I enforce echoing for **all** recipes, no matter whether they have a `@`at the beginning, or not?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861911/ignoring-at-symbol-in-makefiles/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU Make 4.0 there's the option `--trace`. (I don't know how what is the earliest version that supports `--trace`. I just know that 4.0 supports it.)

> '--trace'
>
> Show tracing information for 'make' execution.  Prints the entire
>        recipe to be executed, even for recipes that are normally silent
>        (due to `'.SILENT'` or `'@'`).  Also prints the makefile name and line
>        number where the recipe was defined, and information on why the
>        target is being rebuilt.

With this `Makefile`:

```
all:
    @echo foo
    echo blah
```

A regular run:

```
$ make
foo
echo blah
blah
```

With `--trace`:

```
$ make --trace
Makefile:2: target 'all' does not exist
echo foo
foo
echo blah
blah
```

`echo foo` is output even though it begins with `@`.

Comment: Thank you. The option `--trace` was introduced with 4.0 (see http://lwn.net/Articles/569832/).
I had to upgrade from 3.8